# How do I disable the graphical output of Quake 3?

Tags: c++, quake3

I have been working with the Quake 3 source code for a few weeks now and am in the process of integrating a custom bot as part of my M.S. thesis. I am using a machine learning algorithm to allow the bot to improve over time; however, for testing purposes I would like to disable the graphics out and load up a bot vs. bot match which can play out at a faster speed.

Has anyone done this before or can anyone recommend somewhere to read? I know I have seen this done before, but I have not seen any code examples. I have also heard there may be some 3rd party utilities that will allow you to disable graphics arbitrarily on any application. As a note, I am working with this on Windows if that makes a difference.

Comment: As a basic comment, you should be able to remove the most root call to `render()` from the main game loop, and also make sure to disable the frame wait counter.  You need to double check that Quake 3 still uses a virtual second __and not real time__ to compute its move chunks, or your sim won't run any faster.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a shot and get back to you. Still have some other tasks to work on alongside this.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried running the game in a ["dedicated" server mode](http://wiki.games-over.org/index.php?title=Quake_III_Arena_Dedicated_Server_Documentation)? This mode is usually run on network servers.

Then try combining this with the "timedemo" command somehow to make it run the game faster than realtime.